# Including '0' in numberArray dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, magento

Is it possible to include the option '0' in a dropdown generated by:-

```
'options' =>  Mage::helper('menu')->numberArray(5,Mage::helper('menu')->__('')),
```

This is part of...

```
$fieldset->addField('column', 'select', array(
        'name' => 'column',
        'label' => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Column'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Column'),
        'required' => true,
        'options' =>  Mage::helper('menu')->numberArray(5,Mage::helper('menu')->__('')),
    ));
```

Which generates a dropdown 1-5 but I'm wanting to include 0 at the beginning of this dropdown (or 'none' or anything other value that isn't an integer of 1+) but I'm unsure how to edit the above to allow this.

If anyone could advise what is needed please, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get that helper? There is no 'menu' helper in native Magento.

Comment: No you're right - it's defined within extension package.

Comment: If I need to provide further information, happy to so - if you could let me know please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `numberArray()` is *not* a native Magento method, we can't know what this custom method really does in the end.

But, `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset::addField()` usually expects just a simple assoc array as value for the `options` key, so most probably something like this will work:

```
'options' => array(
    0 => 'none',
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'three',
    4 => 'four',
    5 => 'five'
),
```

Comment: This worked in place of the original code and allows me to include what I was intending. Thanks very much! :)